# Select ... union all. Difference between SQL server 2012/2014

Tags: sql-server

I`am inserting about 1.5k rows (30 columns) like this:

```
insert into table (col1,col2...)
select col1,col2... union all
```

sql server 2012: ~30 seconds

sql server 2014: ~6 minutes

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: How can we possibly diagnose this? You provide no details as to all the configuration of the 2 installations. Are you sure the db structure is the same? You are really providing insufficient information.

Comment: Compare the execution plans on the 2 servers.  If different, that may point to the root cause, such as missing indexes or state statistics.

Comment: Plans are the same. If i`m doing only slect, duration on 2012/2014 is different, as with an insert, so i think this is not indexes. Log space on 2014 even bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Set operators like `UNION ALL` and `UNION` will consume more log space while executing so try to avoid using those.may be your data base log space vary from `SQL SERVER 2012` to `SQL SERVER 2014`

Comment: Are you able to quote anything to indicate that this is in fact the case or is it a guess?